# list array of object add an array typescript in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

i have an list array like this in my typecript code nestjs

```
const data = 
[
    {
      "id_event": 1,
      "nama_event": "Ibadah Sumpah Pemuda",
      "tema_event": "Who Am I?",
    }
 ]

const dataimage =
"imagelist": 
[
    {
      "image": "asset/example.png",
      "name_image": "example.png",
      "id_image": 3,
    },
    {
      "image": "asset/example2.png",
      "name_image": "example2.png",
      "id_image": 2,
    }
 ]
```

how to add dataimage into data?
My ouput should be like this:

```
[
    {
      "id_event": 1,
      "nama_event": "Ibadah Sumpah Pemuda",
      "tema_event": "Who Am I?",
      "imagelist": 
      [
       {
        "image": "asset/example.png",
        "name_image": "example.png",
        "id_image": 3,
       },
       {
        "image": "asset/example2.png",
        "name_image": "example2.png",
        "id_image": 2,
       }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

I have tried using data.push(dataimage) but the result is not like in the example, and i use `data.concat(dataimage)` the result just show data

Comment: `dataimage` is not a valid value. Is it supposed to be an object like `dataimage = { imagelist: [arrayData] }`?

Comment: so i must convert the dataimage to an object? and push into data value?

Comment: I'm saying right now, what you've shown won't run. JavaScript won't interpret it in any way. Is `dataimage` _supposed_ to be an object?

Comment: i dont know exactly dataimage supposed to be, i am just have list of array and i add a  string "imagelist : " to identifier a query... what is the correct of dataimage?

Comment: or dataimage like this?

dataimage =
{
  "imagelist": 
  [
      {
        "image": "asset/example.png",
        "name_image": "example.png",
        "id_image": 3,
      },
      {
        "image": "asset/example2.png",
        "name_image": "example2.png",
        "id_image": 2,
      }
   ]
}

dataimage in array, if i push with data value, the result add new array after data value